# Asynchronously process a list of objects

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a list of objects, and I need to get one object in that list that best identifies a particular item and add that item in that object.

```
List<Category> endpoints = new List<Category>();
endpoints = await GetRelatedCategoriesAsync(pp);
float catScore = 0;
Category categoryHit = new Category();

// THIS LOOP SHOULD BE ASYNCHRONOUS
foreach (Category cat in endpoints)
{
    SentenceSimilarity similarity = new SentenceSimilarity();
    string phrase = cat.Keywords.Replace("|", " ");
    float score = similarity.GetScore(phrase, string.IsNullOrEmpty(wholeWord) ? "" : wholeWord);

    if (catScore == 0)
    {
       catScore = score;
       categoryHit = cat;
    }
    else
    {
        if (catScore > score)
        {
            // Do something here
        }
        else
        {
           catScore = score;
           categoryHit = cat;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem happens when `GetRelatedCategoriesAsync` returns more than 100 records and the process would take too long, I am having troubles doing it asynchronously so what I did temporarily is that I 'uncategorize' the item if the related categories would reach at least 21 objects.

How do I make this asynchronous, I have also read about SemaphoreSlim but I am not sure if that is what I need to be using.

**UPDATE**
After trying out **Yuval Itzchakov** suggestion, I am getting the following error:

```
at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTaskGroupState.QueryEnd(Boolean userInitiatedDispose)
at System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTask.SpoolStopAndGo[TInputOutput,TIgnoreKey](QueryTaskGroupState groupState, PartitionedStream`2 partitions, SynchronousChannel`1[] channels, TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
at System.Linq.Parallel.DefaultMergeHelper`2.System.Linq.Parallel.IMergeHelper<TInputOutput>.Execute()
   at System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute()
   at System.Linq.Parallel.MergeExecutor`1.Execute[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitions, Boolean ignoreOutput, ParallelMergeOptions options, TaskScheduler taskScheduler, Boolean isOrdered, CancellationState cancellationState, Int32 queryId)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.PartitionedStreamMerger`1.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 partitionedStream)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.AssociativeAggregationOperator`3.WrapPartitionedStream[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream, IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient, Boolean preferStriping, QuerySettings settings)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.ChildResultsRecipient.Receive[TKey](PartitionedStream`2 inputStream)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.UnaryQueryOperator`2.UnaryQueryOperatorResults.GivePartitionedStream(IPartitionedStreamRecipient`1 recipient)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOperator`1.GetOpenedEnumerator(Nullable`1 mergeOptions, Boolean suppressOrder, Boolean forEffect, QuerySettings querySettings)
   at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOpeningEnumerator`1.OpenQuery()
   at System.Linq.Parallel.QueryOpeningEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Parallel.AssociativeAggregationOperator`3.Aggregate()
   at System.Linq.AggregationMinMaxHelpers`1.Reduce(IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 sign)
   at System.Linq.AggregationMinMaxHelpers`1.ReduceMax(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Max[TSource](ParallelQuery`1 source)
   at System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Max[TSource,TResult](ParallelQuery`1 source, Func`2 selector)
   at Scraper.UskoopScraper.<GetCategoryIdAsync>d__80.MoveNext() in d:\projects\\\file.cs:line 1001
```

Comment: What do you want to make asynchronous?

Comment: seems like a problem where you can process some parts in parallel ... `async` is a poor solution for that

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i would like to process the LOOP part in parallel to each other or asynchronously, if that makes sense

Comment: @Carsten yes, I also tried using Parallel.ForEach but I get errors I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: yer have you tried using a List of Task ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is `catScore` and `catCategory`? Are they global variables?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No, they're method-level variables, the catScore is the result of the similarity between the keywords property of the Category object and the keywords of the item. categoryHit holds the Category object that's closer to the keywords of the item, I am using a different algorithm to process the keywords and that's where I get errors if I use Parallel.ForEach

Comment: Is it the `similarity.GetScore` method that takes a long time to process?

Comment: @Enigmativity the loop would take a long time if say there's a list of 200 Categories or more

Comment: @shifter You need to walk us through the algorithm. Why are you setting `catScore` and `categoryHit` when `catScore` is 0 or if `catScore > score`? Why not join those conditions?

Comment: @shifter - So that's a yes?

Comment: It looks like you're actually trying to find the category with the maximum score?

Comment: Make async method that does the work in the for each loop then do var tasks = list.select(async x => newmethod(x));  await Task.WhenAll(tasks)   or. Task.WaitAll(tasks);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the exact requirements from you algorithm, but it looks like you're trying to find the maximum out of all categories.

What you can do is define a class which implements `IComparable<T>` and use PLINQ (Parallel LINQ) by calling `AsParallel` and use its extension method `ParallelEnumerable.Max`. It would look similar to this:

```
public class CategoryResult : IComparable<CategoryResult>
{
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(CategoryResult other)
    {
        int comparison = 0;
        if (this.Score == other.Score)
        {
            comparison = 0;
        }
        else if (this.Score > other.Score)
        {
            comparison = 1;
        }
        else if (this.Score < other.Score)
        {
            comparison = -1;
        }

        return comparison;
    }
}
```

And then you'd call your method like this:

```
var maxCategoryResult = list.AsParallel().Max(cat => 
{
    SentenceSimilarity similarity = new SentenceSimilarity();
    string phrase = cat.Keywords.Replace("|", " ");
    float score = similarity.GetScore(
                phrase, string.IsNullOrEmpty(wholeWord) ? "" : wholeWord);

    CategoryResult catResult = null;
    if (catScore == 0 || catScore < score)
    {
        catResult = new CategoryResult
        {
            Category = cat,
            Score = score
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Create different category?
    }

    return catResult;
}
```

Comment: I am using [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) to compare the similarities between strings. I am trying to get the Category with the highest similarity score with the item's keywords. Where should I call `CompareTo`?

Comment: @shifter You don't need to. `Max` will implicitly call it for you when it looks for the maximum value.

Comment: I posted an error from your suggestion, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
       _HResult=-2147467261
       _message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       HResult=-2147467261
       IsTransient=false
       Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       Source=WordNetClasses` somehow my WordNet API would throw an error, do I need to instantiate it within somewhere?

Comment: How are you creating those classes?

Comment: Princeton University released an API that is available for download [here](https://wordnet.codeplex.com) made it into a DLL and called it from my project. It doesn't throw any errors though if I just use it within a simple `foreach`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86795/discussion-between-shifter-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: I fixed the problem from the WordNet API and it's now working, I just need to test how fast it is, thanks for the help!

Comment: @shifter Great! What ended up being the problem?

Comment: It was a static method from the API that's causing an error in the thread, so i changed it to a non-static method